# connection pooling with mongoose in node js with clusters

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose and node js with clustering (server and child processes). I want to create a connection pool that can be shared with all child and master process. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You can only share connections within particular process.

When you connect to mongodb via mongoose, append a "poolSize={your pool size}" on your connection uri.

For example: mongodb://{user}:{password}@localhost:{port}/{db_name}?poolSize=5

You can use pm2 to create and manage your node cluster.

You should aware of the connections that a cluster create to the mongodb server.

cluster_connection_number = pollSize * process_number

For more information, please visit https://github.com/Unitech/PM2